# how to display unicode characters using jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here's the background. I trying to retrieve unicode characters from a mysql server using php, ajax, and jquery in the following code.

```
    $.post("test.php",{tableName: A_table}, function(data)
    {
         $.each($(data), function(key, value)
         {
            display data into an UL List and not display weird unicode characters, like            00101C
         }

    });
```

Based on the code above, how do I get unicode characters to display.

Answer (score 0):

you should force the `charset` header of your response to be `UTF-8` (or other suitable charset for your needs), or you could previously convert all your unicode characters on server side with [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

example (taken from manual page)

```
<?php
$text = "A strange string to pass, maybe with some ø, æ, å characters.";

foreach(mb_list_encodings() as $chr){
    echo mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', $chr)." : ".$chr."<br>";   
}
?>
```